# Javascript to Call Form Objects through a function using form name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a html page in which following function is written.

> I have multiple forms with single textbox and button in each form.
>   form names are different but Text box names are same through out all
>   forms.

Now i need to call exact text box when particular form is clicked.

below is the java script.  f_name represents form name.reject_reason is text box inside all forms.

```
<script language='javascript'>

function validate(f_name){
var reject_reason =document.f_name.reject_reason;

if ((reject_reason.value==null)||(reject_reason.value=="")){
alert('Enter Value');       
reject_reason.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Above function is not calling the exact the text box. It returns nothing.**

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to get the form with the name contained in `f_name`, not literally the form named "f_name":

```
var reject_reason =document.forms[f_name].reject_reason;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .next if the element is below, or .parent if element is above.
But, Send better informations please.
Are you using jQuery?